# Как в своей схеме Vertica обновлять данные?

Tags: postgresql, airflow, vertica

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обновить данные в своей схеме, которую я собираю из множества таблиц.
Я использую airflow для выгрузки данных каждый день.
DAG airflow состоит из 2 частей:

1. `sql_vertica1 = u""" Truncate table table1; """`   --- Удаляю данные из схемы
2. `sql_vertica2 = u""" Insert into table1 (SELECT мой запрос из разных таблиц) """` --- Заполняю таблицу

Таблицы из которых я забираю данные удаляют старые данные, а хотелось бы их сохранить.

Возможно есть способ обновлять данные, которые новые или обновились старые строки, но если строки удалились, то ничего не делать и данные в моей схеме по ним не удалять.

Даты изменения для каждых строк как таковых нет, они агрегируют по ключам, но не по датам, есть 1 общая дата создания, но остальные данные могут меняться, так что к дате смысла привязываться нет.